# Vue dynamic image from assets

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

Below is my file structure

Project

```
|-src
  |-assets
    |-images
----->|-logo.png
  |-components
    |-json
----->|-data.json
    |-mainComp
----->|-exp.vue
```

Now here is my data.json code

```
"Experience": {
    "0": {
      "sectionTitle": "Awards",
      "sectionContent": {
        "0": {
          "articleTitle": "Adobeedu",
          "articleValue": "2019 Early Bird",
          "articleDate": "Acheived on 2019",
          "image": true,
          "articleImgPath": "../../assets/images/logo.png",
          "articleAlt": "AdobeEdu Early Bird Award"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

and here below is the code of the exp.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <section class="exp__section" v-for="(data, index) in jsonTitle" :key="index">
      <h5>{{data.sectionTitle}}</h5>
      <article
        v-for="(items, idx) in data.sectionContent"
        v-bind:class="{'content__box':true, 'contains__image':(items.image === true)}"
        :key="idx"
      >
        <h6>{{items.articleTitle}}</h6>
        <div class="image__row">
          <div class="image__box">
            <!-- <img :src="items.articleImgPath" :alt="items.articleAlt" /> -->
          </div>
          <h3>{{items.articleValue}}</h3>
        </div>
        <p>{{items.articleDate}}</p>
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import json from "@/components/json/english.json";
export default {
  name: "ExperienceSection",
  data() {
    return {
      jsonTitle: json.Experience
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Now src does get the value: `../../assets/images/logo.png` but the images don't load up. I thought maybe I am not accessing the file structure properly so I tried `./`, `../`, `../../../`, `../../../../` but I think this may not be the problem, and I may need something to load the image after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because Vue CLI uses Webpack to bundle the *assets* folder, and this bundling renames the files/path.  So when binding to an asset source, the easiest way to overcome this is to use `require` in the template and hardcode the *assets* path and any subpath.  For example

```html
<img :src="require('@/assets/images/' + items.articleImgPath)" :alt="items.articleAlt">
```

Remove the path from the variable and only use the filename:

```
"articleImgPath": "logo.png",
```

This also keeps the JSON clean of path names.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I didn't considered the bundling, however now that I have the location right and the new syntax as you stated, the entire component doesn't seems to load.

`<div class="image__box">
            <img
              :src="require('../../assets/images/' + items.articleImgPath)"
              :alt="items.articleAlt"
            />
          </div>`

Comment: `<div id="exprience" class="experience">
<!---->
</div>`

Comment: Hi, you're welcome.  Please use the syntax exactly as shown:   `'@/assets/images/'`.  The `@` symbol is a Webpack alias to the project `src` folder.

Comment: ` <div class="image__box">
            <img :src="require('@/assets/images/' + items.articleImgPath)" :alt="items.articleAlt" />
          </div>`

Sorry Man it's Not working out. may be the `@` points to different location in my code.

Comment: It's ok.  This is the correct way, so something else must be wrong in your code.  Have you changed your JSON as above?  What error do you get in the console?

Comment: `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module './undefined'"

found in

---> <ExperienceSection> at src/components/mainComp/ExperienceSection.vue
       <Experience> at src/components/mainComp/Experience.vue
         <Main> at src/components/Main.vue
           <Container> at src/views/Container.vue
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>`

Comment: `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 Error: Cannot find module './undefined'
    at webpackContextResolve (eval at ./src/assets/images sync recursive ^\.\/.*$ (app.js:1378), <anonymous>:12:11)
    at webpackContext (eval at ./src/assets/images sync recursive ^\.\/.*$ (app.js:1378), <anonymous>:7:11)
    at eval (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":`

Comment: Ok, this error means that one of your articles has no `articleImagePath`.  You'll need to check for that with a `v-if` somewhere before trying to render this.  For example, this would work:  `<img v-if="items.articleImgPath" :src="require('@/assets/images/' + items.articleImgPath)" :alt="items.articleAlt">`

Comment: In your question from yesterday, you did have this `v-if` in your template, but now it appears to be missing.

Comment: Yes Dan, You are absolutely correct.
I did the if contition on the article, and I thought won't be required for the image itself.
Thanks again Dan. You are very helpful.